# Dummy data in SplitPage files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

When I'm making a new Visual Studio Windows 8 Store Project (C#), I get dummy data if I start off With a SplitPage, however, if I'm adding new SplitPages to the Project, there's no dummy data coming With it, and I just get a ton of errors if I try the code from the main SplitPage (the one created when I made the actual Project).

How can I get dummy data in the "new added" SplitPages, not only in the main Project file?

Comment: Nope - did a mistake here. The answer has been accepted again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually. You can use `ExampleDataSource` classes which you can find in any example.
Then in XAML code, when you describe `CollectionViewSource` in `Page.Resources` you usually bind data-source in way like:

```
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="itemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding YourDataSource}"/>
```

Here you use `Source` parameter to specify binding. Now use parameter `d:Source`. Namespace `d` is used for describing things, which will be used only in designer (that's why it is `d`, I believe).

So try adding this parameter to your `CollectionViewSource`:

```
        d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"
```

Assuming that `SampleDataSource` has property `AllGroups` and it is `ObservableCollection`, it should work.

Hope my answer helps anyone dealing with Win8 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Microsoft employee: this is not possible. You'll only get the dummy data if you create the splitpage as the first page within a new project.